# Find a string from a website using DOM

Tags: javascript, vba, dom

I am trying to get the number after the word "Request Number" using vba from DOM Explorer. Below is the code that finds the "Request Number:", but I am unable to get the number after that.

```
For Each Element In Elements2
                If Element.ID = "Request Number" Then
                    RequestNumber = Element.GetAttribute("Value")
                End If 
Next Element
```

[image: DOM Explorer Window]

Comment: use .innertext or innerhtml

Comment: .innertext is showing "Request Number: " and .innerhtml shows some code

Comment: Needs more code - what is `Elements2` ?  There is no `id` attribute in the HTML you posted.

Comment: Look at looping elements2 with a numeric index, then use +1.  I think there are some child siblings controls from the containing TD rows, but without knowing the site etc/cant offer more support, with the above.